# Colon syntax error in if statement

Tags: python, syntax-error

Ok, so i'm pretty new to the whole coding scene, and i've been working on python through code academy. On the site there is an activity where you make a pig latin translator. I was able to make this just fine, but when I attempted to recreate it in the python shell I was getting some weird errors in the if statement.

```
pyg = "ay"

original = raw_input("Enter a word bro:")\
if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():\

    print original\


else:
    print "error"
```

I get a syntax error on the colon ending the statement, so I assumed it was some kind of indentation error. However when I put a line space between the line previous and the if statement, it works just fine! Can anyone explain why this is??

Comment: Aside: the `len(original) > 0` isn't necessary, `isalpha()` will only return True if there's at least one character in the string.

Comment: Why are there so many `\\` and so much empty space?

Comment: So I ran your code here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php and it looks like everything is working fine. Although, I removed the \ from the code

Comment: I ran your code on my machine and it worked fine. I'd check not being mixing spaces with tabs (when I pasted the code it was wrongly formatted)

Comment: @Chirvin if one of the answers helped you solve your issue, please accept it with the check mark under the up/down vote box. Please leave "thanks" and other personal messages out of your question as it serves as a record for others to search in case they have your same problem in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ending each line with `\` is what's tripping you up. (See the documentation for ["Explicit line joining"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining))

`\` is the chatacter used to continue a line if you want to have a "single line" span multiple lines of text

The python interpreter sees it and ignores the next newline character and thus sees:

```
pyg = "ay"

original = raw_input("Enter a word bro:")if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    print original

else:
    print "error"
```

when you add the extra space it works because the if statement is again on it's own line

Comment: Thanks man! Exactly what the problem was! I had been originally inputing code directly into the shell, where I was required to use them, when I switched over to using the actual program, it ended up just causing syntax errors.

Comment: @Chirvin glad I could help. I'm curious what shell requires backslashes to terminate each line.. I've never heard of that before

Comment: It was a much older version of the shell, ive updated it now. It may have never even been necessary, as I look back on it now. Probably just read something wrong somewhere lol.

Comment: @Chirvin I added a bit of documentation if you want to read up more on the subject. It seems relatively simple once you know it, but it's a must-know for understanding python syntax.

Comment: Awesome! Where can I find this?

Comment: @Chirvin see edit: ["Explicit line joining"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining) is a link..

Comment: Thanks bro, while I got you here, so I don't have to make another thread, What would be, in your opinion, the best site or resource to learn python? Code academy is pretty ok so far, but there are gaps in the learning, where I need to know something it hasn't taught.

Comment: @Chirvin Early on in learning to program, I tried solving a lot of the problems over at [Project Eluer](https://projecteuler.net/). Tutorials and practice websites will teach you the syntax of python, but time and experience will teach you to think like a programmer.